# ERROR: Failed building wheel for tartiflette

Tags: python, cmake, python-wheel

I need to install tartiflette and tartiflette_asgi but get error:

```
Building wheel for tartiflette (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I had this problem with tartiflette, but `pip3 install --only-binary tartiflette tartiflette` helped me.

Now I have this problem with tartiflette_asgi and try `pip3 install --only-binary tartiflette_asgi tartiflette_asgi` and 'pip3 install tartiflette_asgi --no-binary :all:' but it isn't help.

My environment:

- Windows 11
- Python 3.8 and 3.10
- setup-tools 68.2.2
- ```
  C:\Windows\System32>cmake --version
  cmake version 3.27.7
  ```